# Dojo build to single file

Tags: build, dojo

I want to build my Dojo JavaScript code that I have carefully structured into packages into a **single** JavaScript file. I'm a little confused as to how to do it.

For now I have this:

```
var profile = {
    ...
    layers: {
        'app': {
            include: [
                'dojo/module1',
                'dojo/module2',
                ...,
                'dojo/moduleN',
                'package2/module1',
                'package2/module2',
                ...,
                'package2/moduleN'
            ]
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

Do I really have to manually add all the modules to the app layer? Can't I just say "all", or better yet, "all referenced"? I don't want to include the dojo/something modul if I don't use it. Also, in my release folder, that's all I would like to have - one file.

So - can this even be achieved? Clean Dojo automatic build of only referenced modules into a single (minified and obfuscated of course) JavaScript file?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the examples in [the Layers section of this build tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/build/):

> It’s also possible to create a custom build of `dojo.js`; this is particularly relevant when using AMD, since by default (for backwards compatibility), the `dojo/main` module is added automatically by the build system to `dojo.js`, which wastes space by loading modules that your code may not actually use. In order to create a custom build of `dojo.js`, you simply define it as a separate layer, setting both customBase and boot to true:
>
> ```
>    var profile = {
>         layers: {
>             "dojo/dojo": {
>                 include: [ "dojo/dojo", "app/main" ],
>                 customBase: true,
>                 boot: true
>             }
>         }
>     };
> ```

You can include an entire "app" in a single layer by including the root of that app (or module). Note that if a module in that app is *not explicitly required* by that app, it would have to be included manually. See the second example in the Layers section in the above tutorial for an illustration of that.

You can also define packages to include in your layers, if you want to change or customize the layout of your project:

```
packages: [
    {name:'dojo', location:'other/dojotoolkit/location/dojo'},
    /* ... */
],
layers: {
    'dojo/dojo': { include: ['dojo/dojo'] },
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: There is one important moment - you should copy full content of your `releaseDir` to your server because some *.js files doesn't included in your build (i18n stuff for example).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify all the modules, if the module you add already has dependencies on others. For example, if you include 'app/MainApplication' to a layer, the builder would include all the modules that app/MainApplication depens on. If your MainApplication.js touches everything in your project, everything would be included.
During the build of a layer, dojo parses require() and define() calls in every module. Then it builds the dependency tree. Nls resources are also included.
In your code, you should name your layer as a file in existing package. In my build, it caused errors when I name a layer with a single word. You should code

```
var profile =
   layers: {
     'existingPackage/fileName': {
         ...
      }
   }
```

If you want to have exacltly one file, you have to include 'dojo/dojo' in your layer and specify *customBase* and *boot* flags.

Dojo always build every package before building layers. You will always have dojo and dijit folders in your release directory containing minified versions of dojo filies in them.
Just copy the layer file you need and delete everything other.